# ASP Menu bar, Static view

Tags: asp.net, menubar

I am looking to create a menu bar with a specic type of "action"

Similar to the bar on this website

[BBC Sport](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport/default.stm)

Its totally static and has no dynamic or "pop out" sections. When the top menu is clicked the page will re-load and display the lower level in a diffrent colour.

Can this be achived with the Standard ASP:Menu control?

I am not a big fan of the pop out feature however I do not want all my options to be visible to my users at root

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this basic [ASP.Net Menu control page](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/menu.aspx). You can click on the "Run" buttons to see very basic versions of the menus.

The advantage of using this particular approach is that you can tie it to a sitemap, so you don't have to keep updating the menu code. You just add the page(s) to the sitemap, and the menu picks it up.

You can also dynamically link the menu to different sitemaps, such as one for the admin menu and another for regular users' menu.

The Menu control is in the navigation section of the toolbox.

To experiment with the built-in functionality (before writing your own code to do what it will do for you), just drag and drop a menu control onto your form. Then, use the common tasks menu to:

- autoformat -- good for quick & dirty because it sets hoverstyle too
- set the data source
- set the view type (static or dynamic)
- define menu items with an editor
- work with templates to set appearance

You have to go to properties to set menu appearance.

Comment: Thanks for the full answer! Not 100% what I am looking for though. I am kind of aware of the features of the basic menu bar. Was looking for something that acted like the bar on the website where pop-outs were not needed